# TensorFlow: Classify multiple images from a folder

Tags: python, tensorflow

The code I previously wrote works well on a single image. But now I want the program to run multiple images. I just need to give the folder name as an argument.

I modified my code in such a way that it opens a directory and saves the images but I get an error

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 98304 into shape
>   (1,128,128,3)

on `x_batch=images.reshape(1,128,128,3)`:

```
images = []

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
    image = cv2.resize(image, (128, 128))
    images = np.append(images, image)
    images = np.array(images, dtype=np.uint8)
    images = images.astype('float32')
    images = np.multiply(images, 1.0/255.0)
    x_batch=images.reshape(1,128,128,3)        <------ ERROR HERE

    sess = tf.Session()
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/kubuntu/SimpleCode/.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    y_pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_pred:0")    
    x= graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
    y_true = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_true:0")
    y_test_images = np.zeros((1, 6))
    feed_dict_testing= {x:x_batch, y_true:y_test_images}
    result=sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict=feed_dict_testing)
    print("Up  :"+str(result[0][0]))
    print("Down :"+str(result[0][1]))
    print("Left  :"+str(result[0][2]))
    print("Right  :"+str(result[0][3]))
    print("Forward  :"+str(result[0][4]))
    print("Backward  :"+str(result[0][5]))
```

Is this the correct way of reading images from a folder? How do I classify all the images inside a given folder and gives the prediction for each image?

Comment: And why are you doing the reshape? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @gorjan The input to the network is of shape [128 128].

Comment: You want to read all images at once and then perform inference on them or you want as you read the images from the folder to perform inference on each image?

Comment: @gorjan Read the images from the folder to perform inference on each image.

Comment: I posted a complete answer. I assume you should be good to go now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answers you should do the following:

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
    image = cv2.resize(image, (128, 128))
    image = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)
    image = image.astype('float32')
    image = np.multiply(image, 1.0/255.0)
    x_batch=image.reshape(1,128,128,3)
```

The code failed when you were reading the second image, because the `images` array had two images appended and you were trying to reshape it like there is only one image.

Besides, it's an extremely bad practice to iteratively create `tf.Session` in a for loop and load the graph all the time. I would change the whole code in the following way:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/kubuntu/SimpleCode/.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    y_pred = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_pred:0")    
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
    y_true = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y_true:0")
    y_test_images = np.zeros((1, 6))

    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        image = cv2.resize(image, (128, 128))
        image = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8)
        image = image.astype('float32')
        image = np.multiply(image, 1.0/255.0)
        x_batch=image.reshape(1,128,128,3)
        feed_dict_testing= {x:x_batch, y_true:y_test_images}
        result = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict=feed_dict_testing)
        print("Up  :"+str(result[0][0]))
        print("Down :"+str(result[0][1]))
        print("Left  :"+str(result[0][2]))
        print("Right  :"+str(result[0][3]))
        print("Forward  :"+str(result[0][4]))
        print("Backward  :"+str(result[0][5]))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works just fine now.

Comment: Wonderful! Be extremely careful in the future about my second point. Even if it works, your code will be extremely slow.